# How to have time in multiples of 15 in bootstrap datetime picker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the [bootstrap date time picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) and I want the time picker to show time only in multiples of 15, for e.g. 9:00 , 9:15, 9:30, 9:45.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you want to use [stepping](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/), just set it as:

```
stepping : 15
```

Comment: I guess. This will work. Thanks will let you know in a minute.